# Benefits of unsolicited redesigns

Tags: portfolio, redesign

What are the benefits of unsolicited redesigns of popular apps for a designer? Is it good for a portfolio? What should you pay attention to redesigning the product on which usually works the whole team and millions are spent on research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For a portfolio its better than nothing. Far better to have real projects but if you don't have those then imagined projects don't hurt.
- The key is showing your **process** rather than the end design itself. Nobody cares that you are good with photoshop and can make a website for company x that may or may not look better than what they have now. What they care about is how you came to the conclusion that the bright blue banner was wrong.
- You don't have millions for research? Mention what you would have done if you did. Sure, you might have only done your study on 5 of your friends rather than a global representative sample of this site's users...but that was just down to limited resources. You are very aware of your limitations and you recognise the flaws in your research. That you can work on a budget is a good thing (tm)
- Remain true to the original. If you are redesigning a company's website then redesign that company's website. Don't totally go off and create something utterly different that uses a colour scheme that is nothing to do with the company. Their website is in certain shades of blue and red? You can probably assume on the company intranet is a style document which says that these are the official corporate colours. Of course that  you made this assumption should be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you won't need millions to do some very impactful research. Do face-to-face usability tests on the existing site with just 5-7 people. ([Nielsen says that's plenty.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/why-you-only-need-to-test-with-5-users/)) From those results you'll have a good idea about what your design should improve on. Then do the same on your redesign and iterate until you're happy with the results.